# Change structure of JSON data for API POST request with Django

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a Django REST API endpoint with this structure, that I need to post to an external API:

```
{
    "body": [
        "...",
        "...",
        "...",
    ],
    "title": [
        "...",
        "...",
        "...",
    ],
    "id": [
        "...",
        "...",
        "...",
    ]
}
```

The first item under 'body' goes with the first under 'title' and 'id', and so forth.

The problem I'm having is that the API in question expects JSON data with the following structure:

```
{
  "texts": [
    {
      "body": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "id": "..."
    },
    {
      "body": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "id": "..."
    },
    {
      "body": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "id": "..."
    },
  ],
  "language": "EN",
}
```

And I can't figure out how have my endpoint mirror that structure, with the `bodies`, `titles`, and `ids` grouped together, those groupings nested under `texts`, and with the `language` parameter appended at the end.

The serializer I'm using in my `views.py` looks as follows:

```
class MyReasonsSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    body = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    title = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    id = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_body(self, obj):
        return obj.reasons.order_by('transaction_date').values_list('body', flat=True)

    def get_title(self, obj):
        return obj.reasons.order_by('transaction_date').values_list('title', flat=True)

    def get_id(self, obj):
        return obj.reasons.order_by('transaction_date').values_list('transaction_date', flat=True)

class ReasonsData(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Market.objects.all().prefetch_related('reasons')
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = MyReasonsSerializer
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!

**EDIT**:

Here are the models:

```
class Market(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    current_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2, default=0.50)
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    ...
    language = models.CharField(max_length=2, default="EN")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title[:50]

class Reason(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='user_reasons',
        default=None)
    market = models.ForeignKey(
        Market,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='reasons',
        default=None)
    ...
    valence = models.CharField(max_length=11, default="")
    title = models.TextField(default="")
    body = models.TextField(default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your Json response really is REST ? 
Put yourself in frontend dev place. If you need to consume this API, don't you think it would be very difficult (and costly) to iterate 3 times (body, title, id) to populate some 'list table page' ?

Comment: Thanks, @TâmerPinheiro. Do you have any suggestions for a better way to do it here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would structure it like this...  (its hard to know exactly without seeing the models and trying it out)

```python
class ReasonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Reason
        fields = ("id", "body", "title")

class MarketSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    texts = ReasonSerializer(many=True, source="reasons")
    language = serializers.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Market

class ReasonsData(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Market.objects.all()
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    serializer_class = MarketSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()

        # filter queryset by valence if passed as a query param
        # ?valence=something
        valence = self.request.query_params.get("valence", None)
        if valence is not None:
            qs = qs.filter(reasons__valence=valence)

        return qs
```

Comment: Thank you! Just had to add a `language` attribute to the `Market` model, with `EN` as the default, and then it works like a charm.

Comment: Quick follow-up: The `Reason` model has a `valence` attribute. Is there an easy way to filter the queryset to only return instances of `Reason` that take on a particular `valence` value? I thought I would be able to do it by using `Market.objects.filter(reasons__valence=value)`, but that doesn't seem to work. PS. I've added the models to the original post.

Comment: You could use a package like [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html) but sometimes it can be over kill, I've added an edit to show how you could filter the queryset by overriding get_queryset and filtering by query parameter.